# Running asp.net and node.js as virtual applications in Azure

Tags: asp.net, node.js, reactjs, azure

On Azure I have a Web App Service where I've been running and asp.net server for a long time. This server is used as a REST-api for a mobile application. Now i want to deploy a website, which is implemented as an React app. I discovered the ability to have virtual applications within a single Azure Web App which I believe is great.

I currently have two path set up with a virtual path, '/' leading to the asp.net server, and a virtual path '/web/' that leads to the react folder, as the image shows.
Virtual Path Setup

[image: Virtual Path Setup]

When i try to reach the react server from my browser, an asp.net error-page is showing up, which leads me to believe that asp.net handled my request rather than the react app. If i switch the virtual paths, the react app handles my request no matter the url i try to reach, blocking the asp.net server.

So the Web App is capable of hosting both asp.net servers and node.js servers, but i cannot get them to work side by side, handling requests on different paths.

I have also tried to add /web to the ignoreroutes of asp.net.

Perhaps there is some fundamentals i have missed, because i cannot find anyone with the same issues. I'm asking here because i was hoping someone had the same issues or has some clues. Thanks in advance.

**Update**
If anyone is in the same situation I have more findings in the issue. First of all, if i set the Managed Pipeline to Classic, rather than integegrated in the azure web app settings, Ii managed to reach the node.js application and the asp.net application as long as the root-path pointed to the asp.net app. However this broke some of my controllers in the asp app, and if i made the root path point to the node.js app, the node app still blocks the asp app like before.

My temporary workaround was to set the pipeline setting to Integrated, and separate the two applications into /api, and /web, where the default path '/' points to an empty directory

**Solution**
So its hard to say what was exactly wrong last time, but after cleaning up my Web.config files it managed to solve it.

```html
<system.webServer>
    <handlers>
      <add name="iisnode" path="server.js" verb="*" modules="iisnode" />
    </handlers>
    <rewrite>
      <rules>
        <rule name="React Routes" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url=".*" />
          <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
            <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="^/(api)" negate="true" />
          </conditions>
          <action type="Rewrite" url="server.js" />
        </rule>
      </rules>
    </rewrite>
  </system.webServer>
```

The rewrite rule is what is important here, if it matches the /api-pattern, the request is ignored by react and is let through to the asp server.

Comment: Is there any name conflicts in the route configurations or url rewrite rules of `web.config`? Could you update your post for `web.config` files and route configures of two apps?

Comment: @PeterPan see the final update, it was probably something wrong with the web.config file as suggested.